# Resistor for RF Attenuator

Tags: rf

I'm about to design an 5dB attenuator for RF, using a simple pi resistor network.

The resistor values are 2 x 178ohms, and 30ohms.

The work area is 1GHz to 2.1GHz.

I was looking at different resistor datasheets, but could not see how well they would perform in that frequency area.

I was thinking the resistors probably would start working non-ideally above some frequency?

And how about package size: 0603, 0805, ect.
I guess a small package would add some capacitance?

Comment: At such high frequencies you need to look at datasheets carefully, and layout matters a lot.  Often several smaller resistors are used in series in cases like this.  That reduces the parallel capacitance for the same overall resistance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 405 or 603 parts. check SRF. If power level is too high then you need to use copper dielectric attenuator like coupler, splitter types using magnetic, stripline or microstrip methods.